# Stack Depth Limit Exceeded (After delete trigger)

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
   parent_id VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE child (
   parent_id VARCHAR(30) REFERENCES parent ON DELETE CASCADE,
   child_id VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_parent()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM parent WHERE parent_id = OLD.parent_id;
    RETURN NULL;
END; $$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER delete_parent AFTER DELETE
ON child 
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE delete_parent();
```

Error:

`stack depth limit exceeded`
hint: 'Increase the configuration parameter "max_stack_depth" (currently 6144kB), after ensuring the platform\'s stack depth limit is adequate.'

Background:

- A `parent` can have many `children`
- The schema is designed to so that if a `parent` is deleted, all of its children records are also removed.
- If a `child` is deleted, the trigger deletes the `parent`, and then cascade deletes all the other siblings

This has worked for months and today suddenly we started getting this error.

I can't find while there might be an infinite recursion and I am considering doubling the stack depth limit just to see what happens.

Note: The actual schema is more complex than this and has a few more related tables that have CASCADE delete constraints. But this is the only trigger.

**UPDATE**: So I doubled the max_stack_depth limit and now it is fine. I don't think this is a good solution and I am still unsure how I can for example prevent this from happening in the future.

Comment: There's no need to delete the parent if the delete of the child is caused by the cascade delete of the parent... Can you use some variable to indicate that this is the case and don't delete the parent in this case?

Comment: @Colin'tHart I am embarrassed to say this but I have no idea how to do it. The triggers are something that I am not comfortable with. Do you think this is a solution to prevent exceeding stack limit ?